# Using a text file as input to a Powershell script

Tags: shell, powershell, batch-file, cmd

My group is moving to a new network where we can't directly copy from our computer in Network A to the new machine in Network B.  After years on this machine in Network A, I've got project files interspersed all over the disk.  I need to build a script to copy the folders and files to a backup disk. No problem there, but the network tech guy requires the total byte count to be known *before* copying.

In CMD I've used `dir /AD /S /B > C:\Users\r6540\Desktop\UserFiles.txt` from `C:\` to generate a huge list of directories, including a lot of junk that I've manually edited out.

e.g.

```
C:\Dev\SSIS
C:\Dev\SSIS\DatabaseCleanup
C:\Dev\SSIS\DatabaseMaintTests
C:\Dev\SSIS\EclipseKeys
C:\Dev\SSIS\TemplateProject
```

I've never used PowerShell, but it certainly looks like this task would be within its ability.  I found this:

```
$startFolder = "C:\Scripts"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
"$startFolder -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"

$colItems = (Get-ChildItem $startFolder -recurse | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Sort-Object)
foreach ($i in $colItems)
    {
        $subFolderItems = (Get-ChildItem $i.FullName | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
        $i.FullName + " -- " + "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    }
```

at [Microsoft technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx) and also this, same page:

```
$objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject
"{0:N2}" -f (($objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Scripts").Size) / 1MB) + " MB"
```

The output I'm looking for is the directory name, a tab, and the folder size (without the "MB" as shown above though) and CRLF as the EOL written to a text file.

e.g.

```
C:\Dev\SSIS 70.23
C:\Dev\SSIS\DatabaseCleanup 17.80
C:\Dev\SSIS\DatabaseMaintTests  22.91
C:\Dev\SSIS\EclipseKeys 1.22
C:\Dev\SSIS\TemplateProject 13.29
```

Anyone know PowerShell well enough to troop through UserFiles.txt and get the resulting text file output?

Form doesn't matter as much as function--so if you can come up with an alternate approach, I'd be glad to see it.

Thanks.

Comment: So does the output of your example satisfy your needs and you need a way to just use the text file as input and a separate file as output?

Comment: That's correct.  The output file is basically just the input file with the tab and folder size inserted before EOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward in PowerShell:

```
$objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject
Get-Content c:\input.txt |
    Foreach { "{0}`t{1:N2}" -f $_, (($objFSO.GetFolder($_).Size) / 1MB) } |
    Out-File c:\output.txt -enc ascii
```

This is assuming the FileSystemObject script you found works. :-)

Comment: This works fine, except the separator is a space instead of a tab. Apparently the tabs washed out when I pasted the input file text. The output file becomes an input file for the database upload process, and the space causes an error.  Know of a way we can stuff a tab character there?

Comment: You can stuff in a tab char using `<backtick>t` inside a double quoted string.  See the updated answer.

Comment: Perfecto! This generates the exact file format needed.  Thanks, Kevin!

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach is to use the pipeline more efficiently

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\r6540\Desktop\UserFiles.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\temp\output.txt"

Get-Content $inputFile | ForEach-Object{
    $sum = Get-ChildItem $_ -recurse -Force | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
    "{1}`t{0:N2}" -f ($sum / 1MB), $_
} | Set-Content $outputFile
```

So we take each line of the file and gather the size in MB using your posted logic. The send the output to file. But we can improve on that a little.

```
$inputFile = "C:\Users\r6540\Desktop\UserFiles.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\temp\output.txt"

$results = Get-Content $inputFile | ForEach-Object{
    $props = @{
        Folder = $_
        Sum = "{0:N2}" -f ((Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse -Force | Measure-Object -property length -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) / 1MB)
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $props
}

$results | Export-CSV $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
"Total,{0}" -f ($results | Measure-Object Sum -sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum) | Add-Content $outputFile
```

Only difference here is that we make nice CSV output as well as a total being appended to the bottom since at the end of the day that might be nice to know as well (If I was the recipient of multiple copies from multiple users I would save me a few seconds of effort.) You could just keep a counter in the loop as well for this but this give you an opportunity to see PowerShell at work.

Comment: To get the true size using Get-ChildItem, use -Force to get it to list hidden files.

Comment: @KeithHill This is true.

Comment: The first script gets close, but the separator is " -- ", and I need a tab there, because the output file here becomes the input file for another process.  Thanks for the total/CSV version too--very illustrative.

Comment: @JimtheFrayed replaced with tab